# When Optimistic Concurrency is applied doesn't allow me to edit anymore ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, optimistic-concurrency

When I try to check the box in my data source to check for optimistic concurrency I can no longer edit data. I get an error saying:

"No value given for one or more required parameters."

I am not sure how to bypass this for my sqldatasource1. Also when I try to insert a new record I am missing the field to add the customer id? Below is my code. Sorry still new to this.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="CustomerMaintenanc.aspx.vb" Inherits="CustomerMaintenanc" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView></td><td valign=top align=right>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
            AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ZipCode" HeaderText="ZipCode" 
                SortExpression="ZipCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" 
                ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechSupportConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechSupportConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [Name], [City], [State] FROM [Customers] ORDER BY [Name]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechSupportConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = ? AND [Name] = ? AND [Address] = ? AND [City] = ? AND [State] = ? AND [ZipCode] = ? AND (([Phone] = ?) OR ([Phone] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Email] = ?) OR ([Email] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customers] ([CustomerID], [Name], [Address], [City], [State], [ZipCode], [Phone], [Email]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechSupportConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([CustomerID] = ?)" 

            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [Name] = ?, [Address] = ?, [City] = ?, [State] = ?, [ZipCode] = ?, [Phone] = ?, [Email] = ? WHERE [CustomerID] = ? AND [Name] = ? AND [Address] = ? AND [City] = ? AND [State] = ? AND [ZipCode] = ? AND (([Phone] = ?) OR ([Phone] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Email] = ?) OR ([Email] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))" 
            ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="CustomerID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_State" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_ZipCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_State" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_ZipCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </td></tr></table>
    </asp:Content>
```